# To find Control in Other page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a web application using C#.net
My webpage contains a Hidden Field Control. I need to use this control's value in another page. I declared a method and inside this method i passed the entire page as a parameter. In another classfile i defined this method. Inside the method i tried to access the Controls that was in the page created.  I tried but i can't get the control.

**Code:**

```
HiddenField hdnTotal = page.FindControl("hdnTotal") as HiddenField;
```

Is anyother option to find this control in other class file.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: can you show your code for this? This reads rather confusing given the fact that object-instances of in ASP.NET are a rather temporary thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing a page as parameter did you try using `PreviousPage` property to find a control? On the page where you want the control from previous page you could find hidden file like this:

```
HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)PreviousPage.FindControl("hdnTotal");
```

Answer (score 2):

The normal way to get data from one page to another is to POST the first page to the second page in hidden/form fields.

Is there a reason you're trying to pass the entire control instead of having the control (for example) just set the value of one or more hidden form fields?

Answer (score 2):

You have several options: to use [cross-page posting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx) or to pass the value of that hidden field as a GET parameter to another page when redirecting. Also you can save the value in session or in cookie and access it later.